# Proving that all the sets in a sequence are different

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This is an example that seems to be pretty obvious but I have no idea on how to write a proof:

> Prove that the sets $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},..., \{...\{ \emptyset\}...\}$ are all different.

**This is my try**: since $\emptyset$ have no elements and the others have exactly one, then $\emptyset$ is different from any of them. Since $\{\emptyset\}=\{\{\}\}$ have exactly a pair of brackets and the others, exept the first one, have more than one set of brackets then this set is different from the rest, etc. Continuing in this way untill reaching the last set we will eventually show that every set is defferent from all of the others.

**Note 1:** I dont' know if this argument is valid or too informal. If it's wrong  I'd like to know. If it's informal I'd like to know how to make it formal.

**Note 2:** What about this slight modification:

> Prove that the sets $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},..., \{...\{ \emptyset\}...\}...$ are all different.

Comment: Here's a thought: each one is an element of the one that comes after it. To see this, make up a different notation (as the brackets can get confusing). Perhaps write $\phi_n = \{...\{\phi\}...\}$, where there are $n$ sets of brackets. Then you can clearly see that $\phi_n\in\phi_{n+1}$ and thus they're all different (since no set contains itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $A_0=\varnothing$, and for $n\ge 0$ let $A_{n+1}=\{A_n\}$, so that $A_1=\{\varnothing\}$, $A_2=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$. Fix an integer $n>0$. You’ve already explained correctly why $A_0\ne A_n$; that’s the basis step for a proof by induction that for all $k\ge 0$, $A_k\ne A_{n+k}$. The key to the induction step is this proposition:

- Prove that if $A_m\ne A_n$, then $A_{m+1}\ne A_{n+1}$.

Since the same induction argument works for all $n>0$, you will then have proved that if $k\ge 0$ and $n\ge 1$, then $A_k\ne A_{k+n}$, which is equivalent to that statement that if $0\le m<n$, then $A_m\ne A_n$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prove this by induction. Denote by $A_0=\varnothing, A_{n+1}=\{A_n\}$. Now prove by induction on $n$, that for all $k<n$, $A_k\neq A_n$.

Comment: Sorry, from time to time I also sleep a little. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** You can prove it by induction.

Are the parenthesis in $\{\cdots\{\varnothing\}\cdots\}$ supposed to be finite? If not, this set would contain itself, so be careful.

Comment: (+1) Is it important to change $\varnothing$ to for example another symbol like $x$ in these sets. I mean, is the emptyset playing an special rule?

Comment: @BabakS. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean $x,\{x\},\{\{x\}\},...$ instead of sets above.

Comment: @BabakS. I think not. The thing about $\varnothing$ is that it is the genesis of sets, kinda. Maybe Asaf can give a more meaningful answer. But basically $\varnothing$ is the first set one proves to exist by Specification using some false assertion.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the time. :)